# msvc compiler gives an error, fine with minGW

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, msvc12

I have a simple Qt (v.6.4.2) code that works fine with MinGW64 compilator (Windows 10):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "fftw3.h"

int main()
{
    QVector<int> data = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}; // 2^3=8 values

    //-----Start fft----- (using fftw library)
    fftw_complex in[data.size()], out[data.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        in[i][0] = data[i];
        in[i][1] = 0;
    }
    fftw_plan p;
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(data.size(), in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    //-----End fft-----

    double Amplitude;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Amplitude = sqrt( pow(out[i][0], 2) + pow(out[i][1], 2) );
        qDebug() << Amplitude;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However compilation with msvc 64-bit compilator (v 17.4.33213.308) comes out with errors:

```
error C2131: expression is not defined by a constant
note: the crash was caused by an undefined function or a function not declared to "constexpr"
note: see usage of "QList<int>::size"
error C2131: expression is not defined by a constant
note: the crash was caused by an undefined function or a function not declared to "constexpr"
note: see usage of "QList<int>::size"
error C3863: array type "fftw_complex['function']" is non-assignable
error C3863: array type "fftw_complex['function']" is non-assignable
error C2668: pow: ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

Can I somehow solve this problem, or using fftw library with msvc compilator is impossible? Other Qt projects without fftw library work fine. Project *pro file:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

LIBS += D:\QtProjects\fft\lib\libfftw3-3.lib
INCLUDEPATH += D:\QtProjects\fft\lib
```

Comment: any chance of posting the errors in english or at least correctly unicode encoded?

Comment: tnx, I haven't even thought that output is possible to encode. Edited.

Comment: It's telling you that `QVector<int>::size()` is not `constexpr` but you're trying to use it here `fftw_complex in[data.size()], out[data.size()];`. Other compilers have extensions to allow this but MSVC does not. When you're creating your arrays use compile time constant values when defining the arrays bounds. E.g., `fftw_complex in[8];`

Comment: `QVector`  might be part of the problem here. `std::vector::size` is `constexpr` since C++20, and *can* be used as an array bound (if the whole vector is  `constexpr` of course)

Comment: If you are writing portable code, I strongly suggest `-Wpedantic -Werror` for *gcc*. As well as the usual `-std=C++something -Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use a `GNU` compiler extension (`Variable-Length Arrays`) which allows you to define an arrays bounds with a dynamic value. This is not standard `C++` and is not supported in `MSVC`.

The lines in question are here:

```
QVector<int> data = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}; // 2^3=8 values

//-----Start fft----- (using fftw library)
fftw_complex in[data.size()], out[data.size()];
```

When defining the bounds of an array the value *must* be a compile time constant.

Try changing the above lines to the following:

```
QVector<int> data = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}; // 2^3=8 values

//-----Start fft----- (using fftw library)
fftw_complex in[8], out[8];
```

If the bounds of the `array` aren't known until runtime you'll have to use something like a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: thanks, not it is works fine. Can I define bounds of an array with dynamic value in msvc?

Comment: @Anton Use `std::vector` for that (or `QVector`, if you use Qt).

Comment: @Anton There was a request from back in 2018 for `MSVC` to support VLA's but it doesn't look like it got much traction: [Variable Length Array Support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/about-arrys/402728)